# When to sanitize (remove <script> tags) text entered by a user?

Tags: html, security, text-editor

I give user a CKEditor to enter some formatted text.

Next (to overcome hackers) I am going to sanitize HTML (remove scripts and like).

Is it OK to store in my DB the text sanitized? (Alternatively I can sanitize the text right before displaying.) This way when the user opens the CKEditor again to make changes in his previously entered text, he may see text somehow changed.

Is it a big problem that the text is changes?

What is the common practice: to store text sanitized or sanitize it before displaying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions,

**Is it a big problem that the text is changed?**

> No, it's not a problem but it's not a solution too. If you are not
>   able to store the data saved by the user, it gives a wrong impression
>   to the user about your product or service. Secondly, a change is saved
>   to either continue editing at future date or either the change is
>   complete. By losing these changes, you are defying the actual use of
>   "saving"

**Is it OK to store in my DB the text sanitized?**

> Yes, it is OK to save the sanitized data provided you have properly sanitized it. A regular user might not add any malicious script in the data and the sanitizer does not affect the regular HTML or text. So a regular user will not be affected by the sanitization. You need to handle the scripts by the hacker. And, even if there is a change in the saved data due to script being removed by sanitizer in case of a hacker, you can care less about it.

**What is the common practice: to store text sanitized or sanitize it before displaying?**

> It's always better to store a sanitized text.

Answer (score -2):

You should really be doing both, this way if some malicious code does find its way in to your system it won't do any harm to your site or the users on it when outputted.